# Extract/save a mail attachment using bash

Tags: linux, bash, attachments, email

Using normal `bash` tools (ie, built-ins or commonly-available command-line tools), is it

- possible, and
- how

to extract/save attachments on emails?

For example, say I have a nightly report which arrives via email but is a zip archive of several log files. I want to save all those zips into a backup directory. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: "normal bash tools" -- do you mean using only the functions built into bash (i.e. what you'll find in the bash man page) or do you mean, more generally, command line tools which you could add to a bash shell script?

Comment: @Doug Harris - either.. if I can call `mail` and do this, or save the attachment elsewise, that's fine too :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you're aiming for portability, beware that there are several different versions of `mail(1)` and `mailx(1)`. There's a POSIX `mailx` command, but with very few requirements. And none of the implementations I have seem to parse attachments anyway.

You might have the [mpack package](http://ftp.andrew.cmu.edu/pub/mpack/). Its `munpack` command saves all parts of a MIME message into separate files, then all you have to do is save the interesting parts and clean up the rest.

There's also [metamail](ftp://ftp.research.telcordia.com/pub/nsb/mm2.7.tar.Z). An equivalent of `munpack` is `metamail -wy`.

Comment: Also to add that if you want to also extract the text MIME parts of the email when using `munpack` then use the '-t' option: `munpack -t email_file`

Comment: Thanks for the info about `metamail`. Can you please help me up with [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1299828/how-to-use-metamail-to-extract-mail-attachments-without-interactive-input)?

Comment: Notably `munpack` works on single mails only. When dealing with a whole mailbox file, it needs to be split first. E.g. using `formail < /val/mail/usersmailbox -s munpack` . [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281893/how-to-split-mailbox-into-single-file-per-message)

Answer (score 19):

The best program for this purpose is ripMIME.

It extracts the text and all attachments:

https://pldaniels.com/ripmime/

[GitHub:  inflex/ripMIME](https://github.com/inflex/ripMIME)

Comment: `sudo apt install ripmime`  works though. See also https://linux.die.net/man/1/ripmime . I use this program; works great, no dependencies except libc6.

Comment: good stuff, metamail and munpack not available on Ubuntu but ripmime is and does exactly what expected.

Comment: Thank you! `brew install ripmime` on macOS works well, and then `ripmime -i <input file`. Cheers

Comment: comparing with munpack, it was able to handle better (not perfectly though) encoded file names

Answer (score 2):

- **YES** possible
- This is **HOW** (Resource from [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/70652-extract-all-attachments-unix-mailbox-file.html))

> find dir containing files | while read file; do
>
> create tempdir and copy file there
>
> run munpack on file and copy attachments elsewhere
>
> destroy tempdir (contents)
>
> done

- Here is the **[Perl Script](http://tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4138)**  to do it

Comment: If anyone wants me to paste the Perl script here then just leave a comment

Comment: if you would be so kind (obviously leaving attribution of where you found it :) )

Comment: just read the script ... that's a heckuva lot of perl!

Comment: so you are sure you want me to include that on my answer , it will become very long.

Comment: don't paste here, copying from the original source would be better in this case :)

Comment: btw - shared the bash script I ended up using here: http://antipaucity.com/2014/04/24/automatically-extract-email-attachments-with-common-linux-tools/#.U1lFauZdWtY