# Script Mail.app to auto-save attachments?

Tags: script, automation, apple-mail, applescript, attachments

In similar thinking to a previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/187106/extract-save-a-mail-attachment-using-bash), is it possible to script Apple's Mail.app to auto-save attachments from a given address or file type?

Presuming it is, what would that AppleScript look like?

Comment: This may be suited for stackoverflow since you're looking to program a solution in applescript

Comment: @Daenyth - perhaps .. asked here because it seems app-specific - I'll let the community decide if it should be moved, though :)

Comment: @warren: I'm unsure myself. There definitely is a programmatic solution (albeit ugly). Scan for mails (new since last scan -- store scan times), iterate through the found mails, for each with an attachment, save to a specific location.

Comment: @Daenyth - I've found a couple promising leads via Google, and if/when I get them to work, I'll post my answer here

Comment: Any news regarding this issue?

Comment: @Daniel Beck - doesn't look like it