# procmail recipe not working right for automatically stripping incoming attachments

Tags: attachments, email, procmail

In following-up my previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/187106/), I am trying to use `munpack` in an automated fashion.

I'm trying to do this with procmail.

```
> cat .procmailrc
:0
    | sleep 5 ; munpack /var/spool/mail/testmail ; sleep 5
    /dev/null
```

However, this doesn't do what I expect it to - it's *just* deleting the message (the `/dev/null` line), and appears to not be running the script line.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! need to just pipe the email into `munpack` on its own, which effectively causes the issue to `/dev/null`.

```
> cat .procmailrc
:0
{
    :0 
    | munpack
}
```